# Why do Slice<T>s always have an even capacity?

Tags: swift, slice, capacity

I'm currently using the `Slice` type in a project.
I noticed some weird behaviour, so I decided to take a closer look at `Slice`s. While testing around I discovered [this](http://swiftstub.com/95060134/):

```
var slice = Slice<Int>()
var range = 1...9

let length = range.endIndex - range.startIndex
println("  length of 'range': \(length)")          //prints "length of 'range': 9"
slice.reserveCapacity(length)
println("capacity of 'slice': \(slice.capacity)")  //prints "capacity of 'slice': 10"
```

Now when changing the `range` the `capacity` of `slice` is still always rounded up to the next even number. Why is that?

### Update #1:

Now the first problem was addressed by @MartinR. The initial reason I asked this question was the following though.
Let's add this chunk of code:

```
for index in range.startIndex..<range.endIndex {
    slice[index - range.startIndex] = index
}
```

What I would assume it would do, is to fill `slice` with the values of the `range`. It doesn't though, and actually says this: `fatal error: Slice index out of range`.
When I check the indices though, like [here](http://swiftstub.com/230502575/), they're fine.
Why is this happening then?

Comment: reserveCapacity(1000) actually increases the capacity to 1020, and reserveCapacity(2000) to 2044. That are optimizations to avoid too many reallocations and all you know is that the actual capacity is greater of equal to the requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the capacity only allocates internal memory, but does not increase the `endIndex` of the slice.

You still have to *append* new elements:

```
for index in range.startIndex..<range.endIndex {
    slice.append(index)
}
```

which is the same as

```
 slice += range
```

Or you can replace an empty slice with a new one, for example

```
slice.replaceRange(0 ..< 0, with: range)
```

Comment: Will calling `reserveCapacity(length)` before appending all of the elements still be more efficient, than not reserving the memory?

Comment: @MarcusRossel: If you know in advance how many elements you are going to append then reserving the capacity makes sense to have one large allocation instead of many small ones. But the usual advice is: Don't try to micro-optimize. Do benchmarks (Instruments) and then decide if the allocations are a problem or not.